# Using Azure-Cli to deploy an azure function to azure from Jenkins

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-function-app, azure-cli2

I have created a docker container and generated final artifact of my azure function app code. Azure Cli is already installed in the container. Is it possible to deploy to Azure using Azure Cli and pass the credentials along?

I tried the following command (example credentials):

`az functionapp deployment user set --user-name "MY_USER" --password "MY_PASS" --subscription "MY_SUBSCRIPTION"`

But it results in the following error:

`Subscription 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION' not recognized. ValidationError: Please run 'az login' to setup account.`

If I login (which requires entering a pass code to a browser), then the command above seems to be working.

This is going to be part of CI/CD and manual login is not a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the platform you would use for CI/CD? Azure DevOps?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I use Jenkins

Comment: Thanks. Posted the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed the fact that there is a different login command set for service principals than normal login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a [service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-with-a-service-principal) to authenticate. But since you mentioned you are using Jenkins, fortunately there are [rich set of plugins available for different Azure resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?query=azure) which can handle the authentication for you if you setup in your Jenkins dashboard. For example, in this case you are using `az cli` for which you can install https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-cli/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to be authenticated. Here you have several authentication options: [Sign in with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)

> Authenticating with a service principal is the best way to write secure scripts or programs

[Sign in with a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-with-a-service-principal)